# Alter Table add Auto_Incremented Column with some Initial custom value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of two columns one is auto_incremented id and other is name with some data in it in mysql.

[image]

Now I want to update values of `id` column. With new auto_incremented values let say 1 to 16 values will be changed to 100 to 116. I had try it by doing

```
alter table tmp drop id`
```

and adding new column id auto_incremented. Then i alter table `tmp` auto_increment = 100. But no gain new column added and started from 1 to onward. When i insert new value in Id column then it changed its index from 100. I just wanna update Existing Id values to increment from 100 not from 1.
I google it and search a lot but couldn't find any answer which can help me. 
Any help will be appreciated.
I just wanna change my table as following picture describe with auto_incremented Id.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)** to change the auto_increment value

```
ALTER TABLE tableOutput AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO  tableOutput
   SELECT name, ....
   FROM tmpTable
   ORDER BY id
```

Or

```
UPDATE tmpTable
SET `id` = `id` + 99

ALTER TABLE tmpTable AUTO_INCREMENT=117;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juan Carlos Oropeza.
Nice One.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update auto increment column which is id value with new value with below query :

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 100 WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Comment: it means i have to write 16 queries ,
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 100 WHERE `id` = 1;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 101 WHERE `id` = 2;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 102 WHERE `id` = 3;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 103 WHERE `id` = 4;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 104 WHERE `id` = 5;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 105 WHERE `id` = 6;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `id` = 106 WHERE `id` = 7;

Comment: Any query or any method to update 16 values at once with new order 100 to 116?